# React send new props and then clear state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following situation:

- I have a parent React component and a child.
- The parent has a table and the child has some controls of its own.
- What I want to accomplish is being able to click on a cell in the parent table and have the cell value get transferred over to the child so that the user can edit it there.

This is what I implemented:

- I record the cell value in state in the parent on click.
- When this I record this value, a re-render happens and the string gets sent to the child via props.
- The issue I'm running into is that if something forces a re-render on the parent, that value will get sent to the child again, even though the child may have changed it.

To solve this, what I thought of originally was to send the prop down to the child and then have the child reach back up via a callback to the parent to clear the value in the parent's state. I fall into a loop doing this so naturally it doesn't work.

What is the correct way to send data down into a child component and then have it get cleared post-render?

Comment: Add some code for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

Each React component update will dispatch a re render action. And when a child component receive new props that component will to re render too.

Note that a child item should be re render only if the props values are news o the inner component state have changed.

For your situation I say: you can pass a object to your child component using props, and execute an function in the parent inside of the child. You only need pass the function in the parent to the child component as a prop, after, execute it inside the child component when you need it.

Answer (score 0):

State that is passed down to children via props should be modified by the parent. I would look into '[react lifting state](https://youtu.be/Ke90Tje7VS0?t=7240)'

**Class Component:**

But essentially, your child's handlers (ex. `handleClick`) should be declared in your parent component and passed down to your child component as an onHandler (ex. `onClick=this.onHandleClick`) and in the child can be referenced as `this.props.onClick`

**Functional Component:**

Basically the same thing but you shouldn't use the `this.` reference.